# Consultar quantos Produtos foram vendidos no ano de 2017

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou com dificuldade de fazer essa consulta utilizando `BETWEEN`,
esse é o modelo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzindo seu modelo de dados para `PL/PgSQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE Cliente (
  idcliente BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  salario NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  dataNascimento DATE NOT NULL,
  sexo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Venda (
  idvenda BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  dataVenda DATE NOT NULL,
  valorTotal NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  idCliente BIGINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (idvenda) REFERENCES Cliente(idcliente)
);

CREATE TABLE Produto (
  idproduto BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  nome VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  dataValidade DATE,
  descricao VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  marca VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  valor NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE VendaProduto (
  idvenda BIGINT NOT NULL,
  idproduto BIGINT NOT NULL,
  quantidade NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  valotTotalProd NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idvenda, idproduto ),
  FOREIGN KEY (idvenda) REFERENCES Venda(idvenda),
  FOREIGN KEY (idproduto) REFERENCES Produto(idproduto)
);
```

**Solução #1:** Consulta a quantidade total de `Produtos` vendidos entre `01/01/2017` e `31/12/2017`:

```
SELECT
   sum(vp.quantidade)
FROM
  VendaProduto AS vp
JOIN
  Venda AS v ON ( v.idvenda = vp.idproduto )
WHERE
  v.dataVenda BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31';
```

**Solução #2:** Consulta a quantidade total de `Produtos` vendidos no ano de `2017`:

```
SELECT
   sum(vp.quantidade)
FROM
  VendaProduto AS vp
JOIN
  Venda AS v ON ( v.idvenda = vp.idproduto )
WHERE
  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM v.dataVenda ) = 2017;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/662a8/19